# Twilio StatusCallBack Incorrect

Tags: twilio

I'm developing a vb net application using twilio api.

This is my code:

```
        Twilio.TwilioClient.Init(AccountSid, AuthToken)

        Dim call_to As PhoneNumber = New PhoneNumber("...")
        Dim call_from As PhoneNumber = New PhoneNumber("...") 
        Dim call_option As CreateCallOptions = New CreateCallOptions(call_to, call_from)

        call_option.Method = "Get"
        call_option.Timeout = 25
        call_option.Url = New Uri(ws_url & "/GET_CALL_XML" & ws_parameter)
        call_option.StatusCallback = New Uri(ws_url & "/GET_CALL_FEEDBACK" & ws_parameter)
        call_option.FallbackUrl = New Uri(ws_url & "/GET_CALL_ERROR" & ws_parameter)

        call_option.StatusCallbackEvent.Add("answered")
        call_option.StatusCallbackEvent.Add("completed")

        Dim call_ As CallResource = CallResource.Create(call_option)
```

The call is successfully performed.

Now the problem is:

- if the user answer the call, i receive the StatusCallBack with "callstatus"="in-progress"
- if the user refuse the call, i receive the StatusCallBack with "callstatus"="in-progress" equally

How can i know if the user really answer the call?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If the user actually answers the call, then you will get a webhook to the `Url` that you set, in your example, the one with the path `/GET_CALL_XML`.

If the user refuses the call then you will not receive a webhook to that URL.